# I have a point set in image,how to find the External irregular shape circling all the points by Matlab

Tags: matlab, shapes, point, sift

I got a point set after executing SIFT algorithm.Now I want to find the external irregular shape of those points.Is there anyone knowing the relevant functions in Matlab? Notice that I don't want the convex hall.Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry!It must be convexhall

Answer (score 0):

If you want convex hull, (unclear based on your comment... you can edit questions btw), look up [convhull](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html).

If you don't want convex hull, a [Delaunay triangulation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html) will probably get you started since the result captures both the convex hull of the points, but also the internal structure such that you may be able to remove some edges from the outside of the returned triangulation.